# Puppet 2 file resources in the same manifest

Tags: puppet

here is my manifest, also apologies for the formatting. At the very bottom is the error. How can I refactor this so that it works? I know its telling me that /etc/yum.repos.d is used more than once but I need to use it more than once to accomplish what I need to do, which is remove the /etc/yum.repos.d dir and add it back with the template from my local repo. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class profile::base {

  #the base profile should include component modules that will be on all nodes

#Remove Directory
#file {'Remove_Directory':
#   ensure  => absent,
#   path    => '/etc/yum.repos.d',
#   recurse => true,
#   purge   => true,
#   force   => true,
#   }

#Add Directory
file {'Add_Directory':
   ensure  => directory,
   path    => '/etc/yum.repos.d',
   recurse => true,
   purge   => true,
   force   => true,
   }

#Copy Repo Template in directory
file { 'Copy_Template':
  path    => '/etc/yum.repos.d',
  ensure  => file,
  content => template('profile/local-repos.repo.epp'),
   }
}
```

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Cannot alias File[Copy_Template] to ["/etc/yum.repos.d"] at (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/bastion/site/profile/manifests/base.pp, line: 24); resource ["File", "/etc/yum.repos.d"] already declared (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/bastion/site/profile/manifests/base.pp, line: 15) (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/bastion/site/profile/manifests/base.pp, line: 24, column: 1) on node sshtest.mmps.mcrc.cspm.marines.usmc.mil
```

Comment: The error is valid.  Puppet is a declarative language where you define the state you want the system to be in.  It is not a scripting language where you give it list of steps to run.  You have defined the directory be absent, and that it exists.  That's an error.  You probably don't actually have to delete the directory.  You just need to control what is inside it.

Answer (score 3):

What I guess you want to do is something like the following:

Make sure the directory exists, but contains only managed files:

```
file { '/etc/yum.repos.d':
  ensure  => 'directory',
  purge   => true,
  recurse => true,
  force   => true,
  [...]
}
```

Add a managed file to that directory:

```
file { '/etc/yum.repos.d/your-repo-file.repo':
  ensure  => 'present',
  content => template('your-template'),
  [...]
}
```

Comment: This works, but the annoying thing is maintaining that template for the dozens of configuration options repo files have. It ends up being either inflexible or a maintenance burden.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are trying to do with the native yumrepo resource.

First, purge any unmanaged yum repos. (I believe this is what you are trying to do with the Add_Directory file resource.)

```
resources { 'yumrepo':
  purge => true,
}
```

Then, you can define your local repositories.

```
yumrepo { 'myrepo1':
  ...
}

yumrepo { 'myrepo2':
  ...
}
```

Comment: While you're technically completely right, most people I know prefer copying pre-existing repo-files and templating some of their own. I think both ways (yumrepo and file resource) are valid solutions both with their advantages and drawbacks.

Comment: I agree. I only presented this way as another option. (Even upvoted yours.) OP and any future reader can figure out what is best for them.